# Convert JSON object to List C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have this Json string:

```
{"1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":"1","6":"","7":"","8":"1","9":"","10":"1","11":"","12":"","13":"1"}
```

I need convert this to an array something like:

```
0: Id=1, Value=""
1: Id=2, Value=""
..
..
12: Id=13, Value="1"
```

Or into 2d array

```
[1,0],[2,0],[3,0]......[12,1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried *anything* so far? Questions just listing requirements read a little bit like you're just trying to get people to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved:

```
var all = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(fullData);
```

Give me a list with

```
Key: my id
Value: my value
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could *try* and parse it yourself, but I would recommend a JSON library such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

You can take your original class (Or use a dictionary/array in this case), serialize it to a file, and read it when needed.